# What is the correct code flow while sending a message

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, protocol

I have a fundamental doubt wrt boost signaling used in bitcoin. As far as I understand the following happens between `main.cpp` and `init.cpp`:

- `StartNode()` spawns a thread `ThreadMessageHandler`
- `ThreadMessageHandler` issues a boost signal `SendMessages`
- `SendMessages()` does the sending of messages (like `PING` or `INV`)

Is my understanding correct? Why do we invoke a boost signal and complicate ? Why not a simple function call to `SendMessages()` in `main.cpp` would not do the equivalent?

Any expert please explain the flow of code here.

**Update**

Code Snippet1 (Original Bitcoin)

```
if (lockSend)
     g_signals.SendMessages(pnode);
```

Code Snippet2 (My Attempt):

```
if (lockSend)
     SendMessages(pnode);
```

Comment: When would you call it?

Comment: Please see my update (Snippets).  Is that not equivalent? Anyway there are some checks inside `ProcessMessages()` after which real messages are pushed. Like for Ping to happen -- one will need wait till `PING_INTERVAL` or manually issue it. All these are anyway checked in the function.